# Use latest browser features in Android webView

Tags: android, cordova, webview

I recently inherited a device and began using it as for testing because it is an older device, an imediate issue is noticable when my cordova app launches. There is no CSS3 or ES6 support. What's annoying is the whole app is written in ES6, HTML5 and CSS3. The device is a Galaxy Tablet (SM-T315T) rocking android 4.4.2 after the latest update by Samsung. Checking the error console reveals an error saying CSS property 'grid-column' is not supported and `unexpected token '=>'` and all sorts of unsupported error messages.

I read [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating) that the OS uses the latest chromium version above android 4.4. which mine is.

HTML tag `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, target-densitydpi=low-dpi, shrink-to-fit=no">` also has no effect.

Comment: You will have hard time using any of the *new* stuff below android 5. When consulting with www.caniuse.com it shows that css grid is not supported in android version <= 4.4. Regarding ES6 - you need to use some JS transpiler like Bable, it will transpile your ES6 js code to ES5

Comment: Okay, I might just have to rebuild and transpile the code slightly. should'n take too long?

Comment: Check out webpack (it can be a bit overwhelming at first), but it is the greatest frontend tool so far. Download some simple webpack boilerplate with hot reloading and Babel. Yous should be up and running in no time

Comment: That sounds awesome, I'll check it out!

Comment: Something like this might work. https://github.com/wbkd/webpack-starter . Thou I advice to spend a few hours just learning about webpack first, it is really powerful tool and practically a industry standard by now

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll definately have a look